# Unable to hit client side function (angular)

Tags: asp.net, angular, api, model-view-controller, console-application

I am trying to use Signalr with asp.net mvc and angularjs where I need to send notification to specific user or group.
Here is application flow :
Windows service (using httpclient) --> api --> hub

from hub it  will trigger notification.

Till hub everything works fine, i could see the parameters being sent but after this control goes back to windows service.

I am not getting, why it is happening ?

windows service :

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:39751/");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                HttpResponseMessage response;

                ////GET Method
                try
                {
                     response = await client.GetAsync("api/testdoc/TestHit/" + 12545);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("API Hit Success...");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
hub :

public void TestHit()
        {
            // test 
            //  
            Clients.Group("GlobalNotifications").onTestHit();
        }
angular :


 onTestHit: function() {
            console.log('client test callback');           
        }
```

when i use

button -> api -> hub -> func called,

but where as when i try to hit like
windows service(console for test) - > api -> hub -> no call to client side method

your help is highly appreciated ?